# can not load image in parseTemplate mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am not able to load image in parsetemplate mule esb
It gives me error images/test.jpg not found

My flow is as follow..

Servlet -> ParseTemplate -> Property

I put html page in src/main/app folder as well as in src/main/resources

And I create one folder images in src/main/app and in src/main/resources
html page is as follow..

```
<br>
                    <button id="btnReport" type="image" ><image src="images/test.jpg"></button>
```

I got error images/test.jpg not found

How can I load images in html page?
please help

Answer (score 0):

Parse template is meant to be used to parse files with MEL in it. I don't see how it should fail at all parsing an html tag. You probably have an error in the xml or the file hierarchy.